# Executing function when creating a new table on HTML

Tags: html, html-table

When creating a table on HTML I want to call a function (as the onLoad() used to the body).

But `onLoad()` does not work for `< table >`.

**Someone knows an alternative?**

Answer (score 0):

This is the definition of HTML TABLE: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_table.asp

It is written in the bottom that < table > tag also supports the [Event Attributes in HTML](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_eventattributes.asp)...

Now the real question is, why would you use onLoad() on your table?

Comment: Because I'll create a table for each transaction that is on my database. And depending of the time of the transaction, I'll change the background of the table

Comment: now for that you would need PHP or some kind of engin, or javascript ajax.. :)

Comment: do you have some idea of an alternative? I'm lost in this point :/

Comment: if you dispose of an Apache server to work on, you could do something in PHP example: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_connect.asp       Or you could work width JavaScript Ajax.